# Android Studio 2.1 Import Module Facebook SDK 4.11: Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse Project

Tags: android

I'm getting this error:

> Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse Project

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.11, Android version 2.1.

This is my project

[image: this is my project]

Unable to import 'facebook' SDK 4.11 as module in Android 2.1

[image: Unable to import 'facebook' sdk 4.11 as module in android 2.1]

Please help me find out, how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio, you can import Facebook sdk to your project by adding compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0' inside dependencies in build.gradle file and sync the project.